# Understanding namspace of classloaders? Is it shared between hierarchies of classloaders?

Tags: java, jvm, classloader

We know that classloader in JVM creates some hierarchy. There are exists some model like `first ask parent, after me`.  There exists someting called namespace, I mean something like key-value store from FQCN of class to some internal representation of class.
The question is if such namespace is shared between classloaders in the same hierarchy?
To my eye it must be shared as in another case it wouldn't be possible to encounter a following exception:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation in interface itable initialization: when resolving method "org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGOMDocument.createAttribute(Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/w3c/dom/Attr;" the class loader (instance of org/java/plugin/standard/StandardPluginClassLoader) of the current class, org/apache/batik/dom/svg/SVGOMDocument, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for interface org/w3c/dom/Document have different Class objects for the type org/w3c/dom/Attr used in the signature
    at org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGDOMImplementation.createDocument(SVGDOMImplementation.java:149)
    at org.dom4j.io.DOMWriter.createDomDocument(DOMWriter.java:361)
    at org.dom4j.io.DOMWriter.write(DOMWriter.java:138)
```

We can see that during validation, validator found out that there are two classes loaded by two different classloaders? How does such validation work? Obviously, I expect only "more-or-less" answer, or reference to some resource.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Class loaders do not share namespaces.  Afaik they are 100% separate and classes loaded by different class loaders cannot be shared.  There is a hierarchy of delegation, but the classes loaded by that hierarchy are still distinct.

Comment: So, how to explain exception I attached? There exists some knowledge about the fact that there are classes loaded by different classloaders,

Comment: Each class loader has its own name space but when classes of different loaders get linked, they must agree about the runtime classes of commonly used names. In your case, `org.apache.batik.dom.svg.SVGOMDocument` and `org.w3c.dom.Document` were defined by different class loaders but got linked (I suppose, because the former `implements` the latter), so they must agree about the commonly used `org.w3c.dom.Attr`, but their loaders have different runtime classes for that name.

Comment: Does it mean that each class has its own classloader? Or classloader per thread?

Comment: And what does it mean `got linked`. Both classes were loaded to space. However, what does it mean they they got linked?

Comment: When `SVGOMDocument` implements `Document`, you expect that you can assign an `SVGOMDocument` instance to a variable of type `Document`, and that you can call methods declared by the interface on it. E.g., you could invoke `createAttribute(String)` declared by `Document` on it and end up at an actual method implemented by `SVGOMDocument`. This can only work when both, the interface and the implementation class, agree on the return type, i.e. `Attr`. When both have a different opinion about the runtime class associated with that symbolic name, it can’t work.

Comment: I don’t get your question “Does it mean that each class has its own classloader?”. Of course not. This question contradicts the knowledge you’ve already shown in the original question. And why are you suddenly bringing threads into the topic?

Comment: So, we can say that: there are many classloaders in single JVM and each class/thread refers to exactly one classloader who loaded it?

Answer (score 1):

It's perfectly possible for a class to be loaded by two classloaders in a JVM. In this case, both will have `getClassName()` returning the same, but the two `Class` instances will be different values.

If you're interested in learning more about bytecode and classloaders, I've given a presentation to the London Java Community which was recorded:

https://speakerdeck.com/alblue/bite-sized-bytecode-and-classloaders

As an example, if you create two `URLClassLoader`s that point to the same URLs, you'll be able to ask for a class from each of them by name, but they'll be distinct classes:

```
ClassLoader cla = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL("example.jar"); });
ClassLoader clb = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { new URL("example.jar"); });
Class ex1 = cla.loadClass("Example");
Class ex2 = clb.loadClass("Example");
// ex1.getName().equals(ex2.getName());
// ex1 != ex2
```

Classloaders are nested; you can specify a parent. So both of these would defer to the application (or module) classloader, up to the system classloader.

Comment: So when it is legal to load the same class by two different classloaders why `LinkageError` is raised?

Comment: I think what's happening in this case is there's a `org.w3c.dom.Attr` which is coming from the boot classpath and from the application classpath and there's a type confusion between the two. It's possible that you've got some additional content in `jre/lib/ext` if you're using an older JVM.

Comment: So: 
1. It is possible to load two classes with the same name by different classloaders.
2. During some validation JVM found out that there are two classes with the same name are loaded and it leads to error ?